# Can I save to file an array of objects (or array of json, array of dictionaries) in Xamarin, C#, iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, json, file, xamarin

I have a list of "app" objects that I would like to save to file and retrieve later. I got to save each object to file using "File.AppendAllText(filename, son)" but when retrieving the file it is throwing an exception below:

Saving to file:

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filename = Path.Combine (documents, "app.json");
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    nuint index = (nuint)i;
    App app = appsArray.GetItem<App>(index);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (app, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    File.AppendAllText(filename, json);
}
```

Reading from file:

```
    var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var filename = Path.Combine (documents, "app.json");
    String text = File.ReadAllText (filename);
    Console.WriteLine ("text: {0}", text);
    App appJSON = (App)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (text);
```

Breaks when retrieving the file on deserialize :
"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException was thrown:"
"Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 14, position 1. "

Output of text is:

> 2016-03-24 18:14:47.405 top25[30102:2442745] text: { "Title":
>   "Basketball Stars™", "Summary": "The world’s best multiplayer Basky",
>   "AppIcon": { "ClassHandle": {}, "SuperHandle": {}, "Handle": {} },
>   "AppIconURLString":
>   "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple49/v4/71/1e/ad/711ead80-6f18-3b46-2947-85c4d7b38292/mzl.qvwejzyt.png/53x53bb-85.png",
>   "Rank": 1, "SuperHandle": {}, "Handle": {}, "ClassHandle": {} }{
>   "Title": "Snapchat", "Summary": "Life's more fun when you live in the
>   moment :) Happy Snapping!\n\n* * *\n\nPlease note: Snapchatters can
>   always capture or save your messages, such as by taking a screenshot
>   or using a camera. Be mindful of what you Snap!", "AppIcon": {
>   "ClassHandle": {}, "SuperHandle": {}, "Handle": {} },
>   "AppIconURLString":
>   "http://is1.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple49/v4/ea/1c/21/ea1c2133-acbd-c16f-a8d5-33e254fdab7b/mzl.xydsraya.png/53x53bb-85.png",
>   "Rank": 2, "SuperHandle": {}, "Handle": {}, "ClassHandle": {} }

Answer (score 2):

You are serializing each individual object and appending it to a file, which creates invalid JSON.  Instead, you should just serialize the entire array and write it once.

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filename = Path.Combine (documents, "app.json");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (appsArray, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(filename, json);
```